# Use regular-expression to get an array of address from messy html code

Tags: javascript, regex

For example if I get (as `var a` let's say):

```
<img src="http://123.com/1>2.png" />
<img src=`https://321.com/2<3.png` / >
<img src=//123.com/http.png>
<img src=321.com/http.png /   >
```

from a database and then I try to create a gallery to show all of them by first making them an array:

```
['http://123.com/1>2.png','https://321.com/2<3.png','//123.com/http.png','321.com/http.png']
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
a.match(/<img[^>]*src=['"`]?([^>]+)/gi).join(',').replace(/src=|['"`]|\s|\//g,"").split(",")
```

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/gkbJfT/1) ok?

Comment: @lulianonofrei no, it doesn't match `http://123.com/1>2.png`

Comment: Right, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

This works for your specific examples. If it'll work for all your URL's... Who knows ;)

```
<img.*?src\s*=\s*(?:(['"`])((?:(?!\1).)*)|((?:(?!\s*\/\s*>)[^>])*)).*
```

The URL is in capture group 2 **or** 3.

```js
var re = /<img.*?src\s*=\s*(?:(['"`])((?:(?!\1).)*)|((?:(?!\s*\/\s*>)[^>])*)).*/,
    tags = [
      '<img src="http://123.com/1>2.png" />',
      '<img src=`https://321.com/2<3.png` / >',
      '<img src=//123.com/http.png>',
      '<img src=321.com/http.png /   >'
    ];
      

    tags.forEach(function(tag) {
        var res = tag.match(re);
        console.log(res[2] || res[3]);
    });
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jZa826/3).

Comment: The selected flavor at regex101 is php, because it better visualizes the capture groups. As you can see by the added JS code example, it works fine in JS as well ;)

Comment: What's the verdict ;)

Comment: So, any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a "dummy" img DOM element and just extract src out of it?

Something like:

```
var div = document.createElement('img');
div.innerHTML = '<img src=`https://321.com/2<3.png` / >';
var elements = div.childNodes;

console.log(elements[0].src);
```

Comment: sure then you have to use regular expression to get all the img tag from the messy html code first...